# Reading a text file from desktop at app startup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, text-files, nstextview

I need to display the contents of a text file located on the user's desktop in an `NSTextView` at startup . My code is not working -- is it off track?

```
NSError *err = nil;

NSString *filepath = @"~/Desktop/test.txt";

NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                              error:&err];

if(!file) {

}

[textView setString:file];
```

Comment: I got it ;) Forgot: filepath = [filepath stringByExpandingTildeInPath] thanks

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: It should be posted as an answer, but the new-user restrictions might prevent that happening until tomorrow. @Peter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Shem. Sorry about that.

I fixed it like this:

```
 NSError *err = nil;

 NSString *filepath = @"~/Desktop/test.txt";
 filepath = [filepath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

 NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath 
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                          error:&err];

 if(!file) {

}

[textView setString:file];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the text file looks off ... possibly: `/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/test.txt` Also, try **`NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err description]);`** to see what errors are generated.

Comment: ~ is the abbreviation for the user's home directory, which usually is at “/Users/USERNAME”. You're suggesting that the questioner should try to access /Users/USERNAME/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/test.txt, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Paul - Why did you accept an incorrect answer? Give it some time - there's no rule that says you have to accept the first answer that gets posted.